docker image push to container registry
vineescar@Vijeyakumars-MacBook-Pro palaly-expression-builder % docker push ruleengine.azurecr.io/ruleengine:latest
The push refers to repository [ruleengine.azurecr.io/ruleengine]
bf45d8951c0e: Layer already exists 
f3e1bae0bb3f: Layer already exists 
5b48befaff31: Layer already exists 
fbc8c9dabc6a: Layer already exists 
94643e63d24c: Layer already exists 
8faef4eb93ef: Layer already exists 
c5a4f85fb941: Layer already exists 
0afa6796154a: Layer already exists 
b11bb163e263: Layer already exists 
b779a72428fa: Pushing [==================================================>]  176.7MB/176.7MB
8ada682d3780: Layer already exists 
15bb10f9bb3a: Layer already exists 
file integrity checksum failed for "etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt" 

any one know why this happens?
I am expecting to put the local docker image in container registry in this process file integrity checksum failed for "etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt"  this problem is comming

It is the build caches. Usually a cleanup of docker system prune -a will fix it. Be aware that it will remove

all stopped containers
all networks not used by at least one container
all images without at least one container associated to them
all build cache

Finally, if the issue is still there and if the image is over 100 MB and you build using Docker, increase the allocated memory for Docker engine in Docker settings.
